# Overwriting image while clients are downloading it

Tags: apache, server

I have a cron script which generates a small image (1kb) every few seconds. Meanwhile, clients are accessing the same image. Will Apache handle this or could there be a problem if some client wants to download the image just as it is being overwriten?

Comment: Yes, it could be possible...now, are the clients downloading the image directly from the image path or are you using some script, like a php script, that returns the image to the clients?

Comment: Yes, clients are downloading image directly. I could create a PHP script to return the image but I didn't see any advantage to additionally use CPU cycles.

Comment: How about creating a `lock` file in your cron script...at the begining of the cron script create the lock file, and once the image is created, delete that `lock` file...`lock` empty files are usefull for using them as flags...then in your download script, if the file is present you do not allow the download and wait until the lock file is erased...you can do that within a while loop or something similar.

Comment: Thanks, your input is appreciated. This seems to be quite a lot of work (I have many cron scripts). Do you know if there is any way to make this automatic, e.g. with some apache mod?